# How would Troll Logic be used to take over the world?

Tags: warfare

The troll leader calls you to his throne and says "troll general, I must <s>steal</s> <s>dominate</s> acquire the world. As an expert in troll warfare, you must draw up the plans for this acquisition."

So you have a population of about a 10 million trolls. The trolls have the ability to use *troll logic*. Troll logic is where you use reasoning with only slight flaws, but results, that, well, normally couldn't happen. At least if you're not a troll.

The basic Troll logics range from Troll Physics to Troll Sociology. Generally, the magnitude of troll logic you can use depends on the purity, as defined [here](http://xkcd.com/435/). Basic infantry can be trained in enough troll physics that they can fly a magnet pulled vehicle, the entire troll population can only produce enough troll sociology to produce high-quality, but mundane, propaganda.

- Troll Physics is the brunt of what the trolls use. It is powerful enough for various weapons and means of transportation.
- Troll Chemistry is about as powerful as alchemy.
- Troll Economics would allow a secret agent troll to gather wealth while on a mission, but isn't strong enough to crash the economy of a country
- Troll Psychology is about as powerful as Jedi mind tricks
- Troll Sociology is powerful enough to produce propaganda, or similarly powered stunts.
- Various other fields, scientific or not, fall in various places. There is Troll history, Troll international law, Troll politics, etc...

  - In fact, you are an expert in Troll warfare.

Also, how well troll logic is used influences its power. Out-of-universe, the power is proportional to the magnitude of the emotional response it causes an expert in the field (humor and disgust are both fine).

The difficulty of a troll logic task is determined by the magnitude of the effect. No matter how much troll physics you have, you probably couldn't deorbit the moon.

By the way, you may be wondering about mathematics. There is a troll version of mathematics, but it isn't called troll mathematics. Instead it is called INSANE TROLL LOGIC, the most dangerous kind. It so dangerous, that is usually on used as a last resort.

- INSANE TROLL LOGIC is extremely powerful. A INSANE LOGIC TROLL possibly *could* deorbit the moon, with backup from physics trolls.
- It is also **dangerous**. As well as deorbiting the moon, you could accidentally turn all infantrymen into Justin Bieber, or blow up your base via the [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).
- INSANE TROLL LOGIC can use the powers of any other troll logic.
- The safest form of INSANE TROLL LOGIC are [paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_paradoxes) that confuse even mathematicians, but even these would only be used for a good reason.

---

Okay, so my question is, troll general, what way to over the world is most likely to succeed. Remember, an answer must be in a *Troll-esque* dialect. Explain the troll logic behind each thing you do.

Comment: Uhhh... So are you just trolling us with this question?

Comment: @Samuel Problem?

Comment: I've got you an interesting answer unfortunately I don't speak troll. I even did a trial run to see if my strategy works, the plan goes too well in fact I can't find you a translator!

Comment: @user6760 English is fine then.

Comment: sounds a lot like what little I know of warhammer orks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Troll General Ugg know **red** thing go fast.
Troll General Ugg know INSANE TROLL LOGIC bad.
Troll General Ugg know world leaders like MAD.

Troll General Ugg use Troll psychology to talk to world leader and convince them of Troll logic.

Troll General Ugg get INSANE TROLL LOGICIAN to work out equation for Armageddon.

Troll General Ugg sedate INSANE TROLL LOGICIAN .

Troll General Ugg paint INSANE TROLL LOGICIAN **red**.

Troll General Ugg point out to world leaders that, should the insane troll logician wake up, he's going to very, very quickly work out the ideal equation for Armageddon, leading to the world ending. Or possibly just turning into strawberry Angel Delight. This will of course convince the world leaders of the futility of continuing to oppose the great Troll Leader's wishes, leading them to rapidly capitulate and submit to his wise rule.

???

Troll General Ugg Profit...